# question about extension functions in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Implement extension functions Int.r() and Pair.r() and make them convert Int and Pair to RationalNumber.

fun Int.r(): RationalNumber = TODO()   //RationalNumber(this,1)

fun Pair.r(): RationalNumber = TODO()  //RationalNumber(first,second)

data class RationalNumber(val numerator: Int, val denominator: Int)

I have no idea why they are correct answers, please help me out!

Comment: You might get an answer if you were more clear about what you are confused about. How extension functions work? The math behind rational numbers?

Comment: Your example looks like a homework problem you want others to solve, even though you may only be asking for why the comments are correct. You may want to edit your question.

Comment: What do you mean, "they are correct", do you mean, "why does it compile"?

Comment: I cannot believe you actually posted this. There is a button to show the correct answer at the end of the question on Koans, why not just click them instead of posting here?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if that will work, the answer is no.

If you are asking how you can make it work the answer is:

```
data class RationalNumber(val numerator: Int, val denominator: Int)

fun Int.r() = RationalNumber(this, 1)

fun Pair<Int, Int>.r() = RationalNumber(this.first, this.second)
```

You got the Int function alright but with the Pair you have to include the type of the first and second object.